# How to drop into a repl inside a clojure function and print the stack traces

Tags: clojure

Given the following function

```
(defn func []
  (break!))
```

I want the break! function to start a repl, and inside that repl I can print the callstacks that invokes `func`.

The feature is like `ipdb` in Python, which comes quite handy when we want to interactively investigate inside the runtime of some function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very basic version could just be:

```clj
(defn break! [] (clojure.main/repl))
```

That will start a new, nested REPL, and when you exit it (with ^D -- or ^Z on Windows), it will continue on.

You can't evaluate locals, but if you write `break!` as a macro, you can at least *display* the active locals before starting the REPL:

```clj
user=> (defmacro break! []
         (let [locals (into {} (map (juxt keyword identity)) (keys &env))] 
           (prn locals) 
           (clojure.main/repl :prompt #(print "nested> "))))
#'user/break!
user=> (defn foo "Using the break! function." [a b] (break!))
#'user/foo
user=> (foo 13 42)
{:a 13, :b 42}
nested> (doc foo)
-------------------------
user/foo
([a b])
  Using the break! function.
nil
nested> ^D
nil
user=>
```

If you want the stacktrace as data inside the nested REPL, you can evaluate `(:trace (Throwable->map (Throwable.)))`